# When I create an account on my web page using firebase, it doesn't show up on the authentication console

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I recently started using Firebase as a beginner to incorporate user registration functionality into my website. While working on it, I encountered an issue. When I click the registration button, Firefox's developer tools save the password, but the user doesn't appear to register in the Firebase Authentication console.

This is my JS Code:

```
// Import Firebase modules
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";
```

```
// Initialize Firebase app
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);

// Connect Firebase Auth emulator for local testing
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:5500");

// Add an event listener for a button with the id 'btnSignup'
const btnSignup = document.getElementById("btnSignup");
btnSignup.addEventListener("click", createAccount);

function createAccount() {
  var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value;

  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // User signed up successfully
      const user = userCredential.user;
      alert("User Signed Up!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle registration error
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      alert(errorMessage);
    });
}
```

This is my html code:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Register
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" required>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSignup">Register</button>
                            
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone suggest me reasons why this happens?

I watched many more videos, and even checked out the firebase documentation.I tried many alterations but it still didn't work.

Comment: You have the emulator connected, check your local emulator auth dashboard.